# Need to recover C++ code from binary of server and client

Tags: ida, disassembly, c++, disassemblers, interoperability

We have an old 2D space shooter multiplayer game community form late 1990s. The game is still alive today but the problem is the creators of the game are no where to be found and the source code is missing. Although, still functional the client and server badly need some updates. For example, all download speeds are capped for 56k connections... So I'm a java developer by trade and I tried to use IDA but I feel like I'm not qualified to try to disassemble client/server that were written in C++ and probably have built in security for such purposes. I want to learn IDA but i'm just so busy atm with other projects but I would like to solve this problem some how or at least investigate what is possible.

1. Is it possible to fully reverse engineer the legacy C++ code?
2. Is it possible to partially reverse engineer and maybe at least adjust some constant values that are embedded inside the exe
3. Are there any disassembly service companies that specialize in this task?

the game is called Continuum/Subpsace.

http://www.getcontinuum.com/    (link to client installer)

Sample enhancements:

1. Increase the cap value on download/upload speed for greater than 56k connections
2. Allow the client to download and play mp3 files (currently on does .wav files)
3. If possible ability to upgrade graphics library used
4. Allow for editing of key/value properties in game (right now you have to exit the game to change certain properties)

Comment: Do you have *any* documentation at all? Map or object files, notes, sketches, flow diagrams? A fully working Debug Build, for example, would help tremendously.

Comment: Yes the game is very active. You can install the game and download maps from any active sever. I am not sure how the underlying application works programmatically I did not develop the original code. No debug build I think if we had prolly have access to the underlying code as well

Comment: I'll try to explain how it works. The continuum40.exe client loads a U.I that allows the configuration of keyboards settings, any user settings, or fixed values. This U.I also presents a list of potential servers that it can connect to with their statistics. Once you select a server and click "connect". When you connect to the server binary it loads I believe openGL graphics and uses the subspace protocol (http://wiki.minegoboom.com/index.php/UDP_Game_Protocol) to communicate with the server. The packets are encrypted. I can provide server binary if needed. Server forum: https://shanky.com/

Comment: But no I don't have any any technical knowledge of the underlying application. I can only deduce what I see as a user. Over the years the community has been able to write an open source server (ASSS) based on the SS protocol but nobody has put in an effort to rewrite the client. Like I said the game still functions and the community is still active but it desperately needs minor enhancements to the client/server to modernize the game.

Comment: Hah - I  overlooked you confessing you're not one of the programmers. The 'object' and 'map' files I alluded to are *intermittant* files, created by a compiler. They contain valuable information on how the main executable got glued together ("linking"). So I gather you don't have those either.

Comment: Unfortunately No I could maybe ask others but I none of the original developers are still around. The game has been maintained by the community without any updates to the client since 2002/3. We've gotten away with it all these years but I think it's finally catching up to us as it is slowly dying now due to lack of ability to enhance.

Comment: If you don't want to completely reverse engineer the source, you can hook the game by injecting DLLs and modifying code at runtime. It's what cheaters do to create game hacks, but you can use it to improve it instead.

Comment: @AcidShout whatever is easiest I just want to know what is possible. I tried loading client .exe into IDA but it failed to "decode" it. Some one mentioned earlier that the client .exe is encrypted with "PEX 99". Is there a tutorial that shows how to decrypt the .exe and dll inject? And I'm really not sure how to dll inject if I have no knowledge of the inter working of the existing logic? I also added some sample enhancements I would like to do in the original post.

Comment: [Check the CreateRemoteThread & LoadLibrary injection technique here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces). You can automate that by coding a program which will list all the files inside a folder and inject them (easily pluggable binary files). As for unpacking the file, you can check [this link](https://forum.tuts4you.com/topic/23172-pex-unpacker/).

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't look like an overly complicated game, specially in the graphics... If I were you, I'd concentrate my efforts in a full open-source remake, rather than suffer trying to reverse engineer the existing binaries...

Comment: @glampert there is an effort on the way already. https://github.com/Periapsis/aphelion . I just wanted to see how "easy" it was to possibly make some small patches in the mean time. Open source effort is not trivial though (if you look at all the open tickets)

Comment: @AcidShout hmm I tried the link to those PEX .99 unpacking utils all of them throw errors and say pex signature is not found for the Continuum.exe client or Continuum040.exe.  Yea using Peid .95 says it's PEX .99 :/ . Weird if you try to compress continuum.exe with PEX .99 says it is already compressed so the compress utility detected the signature but the unpackers do not.

Comment: Looking at the Decompress.ASM for one of the unpackers it on line 208 says "    push    eax    ; Bad luck. No matching versions to be found. push    offset szInvalidChecksum" :(

Comment: @Airduster I don't have experience with that packer, but my guess is that you can unpack it a-la-UPX, so just search how to unpack UPX manually (or MPRESS for that matter), and follow the instructions for your binary.

Alternatively, dump the binary from memory on runtime, fix IAT, and done.

Then you can patch whatever you want, which is, most of the times, much easier than recreating the game. [talking from a bit of experience modding games]

Comment: @AcidShout I found a utility called "PackerBreaker" that was able to successfully unpack it and I also successfully loaded the exe into IDA Pro... now I need to learn how to read assembly to figure out what the heck is going on lol... progress

Comment: @Airduster good job! now, before you continue googling, keep something in mind: assembly is NOT as scary as some people tell it is.

Answer (score 1):

I checked client exe file and it looks like Pack Master 1.0 (PEX 0.99 Clone) was used to encrypt binary. So first step would be to unpack EXE file. From that point some binary patching might be possible. 
There is another way of making changes. There is possibility to inject new or changed functionality using dll injection.

Comment: I tried 3 different PEX 0.99 unpackers suggested by acidShout all of them threw errors and said couldn't find the signature. I have the Peid .95 and I see it identifies the continuum.exe as compressed with PEX 0.99. Any ideas how to proceed further?

Comment: The main problem is that it it not PEX 0.99. It just clone of it. Pack Master 1.0 uses different algorithm.